# How to compare one element in an array with all the other elements in another array? And repeating it for n elements in the first array? Using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, string-comparison

In the below XML I need to compare the `OrderShipmentItems`s `LineItemNbr` value (Example: 000010) with  all the `OrderItems/ScheduleLineItems`'s `LineItemNbr` (000010, 000020, 000030, 000040) in the first iteration.

Repeat this comparison for all the OrderShipmentItem LineItemNbr's (000010,000020). According to given xml it should be 2 times.

If they are equal map the DelivereQty value to the Quantity attribute of order element and customerNbr to the customercontact attribute of order element.

```
<Orders>
  <OrderEvent>
    <SAPOrderLineNbrs>
      <LineItemNbr>000010</LineItemNbr>
      <LineItemNbr>000020</LineItemNbr>
    </SAPOrderLineNbrs>
  </OrderEvent>
  <OrderHeader>
    <OrderItems>
      <LineItemNbr>000010</LineItemNbr>
      <ScheduleLineItems>
        <LineItemNbr>000010</LineItemNbr>
        <CustomerNbr>22222222</CustomerNbr>
      </ScheduleLineItems>
    </OrderItems>
    <OrderItems>
      <LineItemNbr>000020</LineItemNbr>
      <ScheduleLineItems>
        <LineItemNbr>000020</LineItemNbr>
        <CustomerNbr>11111111</CustomerNbr>
      </ScheduleLineItems>
    </OrderItems>
    <OrderItems>
      <LineItemNbr>000030</LineItemNbr>
      <ScheduleLineItems>
        <LineItemNbr>000030</LineItemNbr>
        <CustomerNbr>33333333</CustomerNbr>
      </ScheduleLineItems>
    </OrderItems>
    <OrderItems>
      <LineItemNbr>000040</LineItemNbr>
      <ScheduleLineItems>
        <LineItemNbr>000040</LineItemNbr>
        <CustomerNbr />
      </ScheduleLineItems>
    </OrderItems>
    <OrderShipment>
      <OrderShipmentItems>
        <LineItemNbr>000010</LineItemNbr>
        <OrderShipmentScheduleItems>
          <DeliveredQty>1.000</DeliveredQty>
        </OrderShipmentScheduleItems>
      </OrderShipmentItems>
      <OrderShipmentItems>
        <DeliveredQty>2.000</DeliveredQty>
        <LineItemNbr>000020</LineItemNbr>
        <OrderShipmentScheduleItems>
          <DeliveredQty>2.000</DeliveredQty>
        </OrderShipmentScheduleItems>
      </OrderShipmentItems>
    </OrderShipment>
  </OrderHeader>
</Orders>
```

My Output should contain same number of orders as LineItemNbr (In the above it is 2) and we need to check OrderShipmentItems's LineItemNbr value (Example: 000010) with all the OrderItems/ScheduleLineItems's LineItemNbr (000010, 000020, 000030, 000040) for every lineItemNbr.

If they are equal then we need to map DeliveredQty value as Quantity and CustomerNbr as CustomerContact.

Output should be:

```
 <Orders> 
    <Order Quantity="1.000" CustomerContact="222222222"/>
    <Order Quantity="2.000" CustomerContact="111111111"/>
  <Orders>
```

Please help me

What I have tried is the below xslt but it is comparing only first list element value.

```
    <xsl:for-each select="/*/OrderHeader/OrderShipment/OrderShipmentItems">
<order>
      <xsl:for-each select="/*/OrderHeader/OrderItems/ScheduleLineItems">
        <xsl:if test="/*/OrderHeader/OrderShipment/OrderShipmentItems/LineItemNbr = /*/OrderHeader/OrderItems/ScheduleLineItems/LineItemNbr">
          <xsl:attribute name="Quantity">
            <xsl:value-of select="/*/OrderHeader/OrderShipment/OrderShipmentItems/OrderShipmentScheduleItems/DeliveredQty" />
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="CustomerContact">
            <xsl:value-of select="/*/OrderHeader/OrderItems/ScheduleLineItems/CustomerNbr" />
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
</order>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Your description is not clear. In general, you would use a [key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#key) tp resolve cross references.

Comment: You don't need to repeat XSLT in the question title - that's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question would be a lot clearer if you showed the expected output. See if this simplified example can help:

**XSLT 1.0/2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="shipment" match="OrderShipmentItems" use="LineItemNbr" />

<xsl:template match="/Orders">
    <result>
        <xsl:for-each select="OrderHeader/OrderItems/ScheduleLineItems">
            <item>
                <xsl:copy-of select="LineItemNbr | CustomerNbr"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="key('shipment', LineItemNbr)/OrderShipmentScheduleItems/DeliveredQty"/>
            </item> 
        </xsl:for-each>     
    </result>   
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input XML example, this will produce:

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>
  <item>
    <LineItemNbr>000010</LineItemNbr>
    <CustomerNbr>22222222</CustomerNbr>
    <DeliveredQty>1.000</DeliveredQty>
  </item>
  <item>
    <LineItemNbr>000020</LineItemNbr>
    <CustomerNbr>11111111</CustomerNbr>
    <DeliveredQty>2.000</DeliveredQty>
  </item>
  <item>
    <LineItemNbr>000030</LineItemNbr>
    <CustomerNbr>33333333</CustomerNbr>
  </item>
  <item>
    <LineItemNbr>000040</LineItemNbr>
    <CustomerNbr/>
  </item>
</result>
```

---

***-- added --***

Applying the same principle in the opposite direction is rather trivial:

**XSLT 1.0/2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="order-item" match="OrderItems" use="LineItemNbr" />

<xsl:template match="/Orders">
    <Orders>
        <xsl:for-each select="OrderHeader/OrderShipment/OrderShipmentItems">
            <Order Quantity="{OrderShipmentScheduleItems/DeliveredQty}" CustomerContact="{key('order-item', LineItemNbr)/ScheduleLineItems/CustomerNbr}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>     
    </Orders>   
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Orders>
  <Order Quantity="1.000" CustomerContact="22222222"/>
  <Order Quantity="2.000" CustomerContact="11111111"/>
</Orders>
```

Comment: Output should be

<Orders>
   <Order>
      <OrderLine Quantity="1.000" CustomerContact="222222222"/>
      <OrderLine Quantity="2.000" CustomerContact="111111111"/>
   </Order>
<Orders>

Comment: See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Thank you @michael.hor257k